# Pandas combining same row into new column while preserving the row(not a simple group-by)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I am a pandas beginner and in need of some help.

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
ID         Val-A   Val-B

aab12      lower   -30
dbc11      lower   -10
aab12      upper   50
dbc11      upper   20
```

I want to produce a new dataframe from the previous one and can't think of a way to do it:

```
ID         Val-A  Val-B  upper-lower
aab12      lower  -30    80
aab12      upper  50     80
dbc11      lower  -10    30
dbc11      upper  20     30
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for nice monotonic unique index and then [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) and `sum`:

```
df = df.sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
df['upper-lower'] = df['Val-B'].abs().groupby(df['ID']).transform(sum)

print (df)
      ID  val-A  Val-B  upper-lower
0  aab12  lower    -30           80
1  aab12  upper     50           80
2  dbc11  lower    -10           30
3  dbc11  upper     20           30
```

Comment: If it is 50,30, (not negative):-)

Comment: I need it to work with negatives that's why I gave this exact example...

Comment: @Tom - So is possible use `abs` ?

Comment: if abs solves this issue then yeah, I was referring to what @Wen said

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two positive number:

```
df['upper-lower']=df.groupby('ID')['Val-B'].apply(lambda x : x.diff().abs().bfill())
df.sort_values('ID')
Out[394]: 
      ID  Val-A  Val-B  upper-lower
0  aab12  lower    -30         80.0
2  aab12  upper     50         80.0
1  dbc11  lower    -10         30.0
3  dbc11  upper     20         30.0
```